# Helm-mini: Emacs is "freeze" very often

Tags: helm

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1, Helm helm-20180212.2045

1. Run shell
2. In she run Android command `adb logcat -vtime`
3. Here result
   [image]
   Nice
4. `M-x C-x b` - show `helm-mini` buffer
   Nice
   [image]
5. Than select shell buffer
6. Again `M-x C-x b` - show `helm-mini`

But sometime (I don't know when) I input `M-x C-x b` and `helm-mini` buffer not show very long time. Show progress bar. Smt like "freeze" Emacs.
Why this hapend?

Comment: Sounds like a Helm bug. Consider reporting it to the Helm maintainer.